# how to change current path for upload when working with ajax

Tags: php

The following problem appears:
I have a drag and drop area for file uploading and a normal form:

Drag and drop:

```
    <div class="sfmform" id="drop-area"><h3 class="drop-text">Drag and Drop Images Here</h3></div>
```

Below a normal form:

```
    <form class="sfmform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <b>Upload Files</b>
         <br /><br />
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="Button Primary" name="upload" value="Upload" />
            <br /><br />

    </form>
```

This is how i handle the upload with php:

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
   // file is ready to be uploaded     
   $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $newFilePath = $dir.'/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
   if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
   //echos successful upload
   }
}
```

The variable `$dir` changes everytime; i read this from the current url like this:

```
// read actual dir from url
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$strArr = explode("=",$actual_link);
$CurrentPath = $strArr[1];

if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
$dir = $CurrentPath;
}
```

So if the url string is like this: example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1
`$dir` has the value: `uploads/sfm/root/folder1`

The problem: uploading with the normal form puts the file in folder1
But uploading with drag and drop puts the file ALWAYS in root. 
Both follow the same php for uploading like above.
Probably, when uploading via drag and drop, he can not read the value from `$dir`

This is my ajax call:

```
function uploadFormData(formData) {
$.ajax({
url: "sfm",
type: "POST",
data: formData,
contentType:false,
cache: false,
processData: false,
success: function(data){
    $('#drop-area').append(data);
}
});
}
```

The php code for uploading is in the same file as the drag and drop div with the form. The file is called: `sfm.php`

Why is uploading via drag and drop not possible in subfolders?

**Update:**
this is the complete javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#drop-area").on('dragenter', function (e){
e.preventDefault();
});

$("#drop-area").on('dragover', function (e){
e.preventDefault();
});

$("#drop-area").on('drop', function (e){    
e.preventDefault();
var sfmfile = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
createFormData(sfmfile);
});
});

function createFormData(sfmfile) {
var formFile = new FormData();
formFile.append('file', sfmfile[0]);
uploadFormData(formFile);
}

function uploadFormData(formData) {
$.ajax({
url: "sfm",
type: "POST",
data: formData,
contentType:false,
cache: false,
processData: false,
success: function(data){
    $('#drop-area').append(data);
}
});
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass your `$dir` as in `POST ` with the `formData` through ajax and then grab it at PHP side and do whatever you do there..!

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai can you gine me an example how to do that?

Comment: Where is your `$dir` code present is it available at the page where you have the ajax code available?

Comment: yes, the ajax is between <script> elements at the same page

Comment: Why don't you add a hidden field to your upload form and pass the dir value through that through the ajax form??

Comment: Also where does `formData` comes from in your code as it shows in ajax???

Comment: post above updated; complete js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution already found. This is how it should be:

```
function uploadFormData(formData) {
$.ajax({
url: "<?php 'sfm?dir='.$dir; ?>",
type: "POST",
data: formData,
contentType:false,
cache: false,
processData: false,
success: function(data){
    $('#drop-area').append(data);
}
});
}
```

The path must be defined in the url of the ajax

Comment: Yup...Can be done like this way also..! But the one which I showed you is more secure since yours one use `GET` method to pass arguments in URL so that's why it's not secure to do it like this way..!

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly how you can pass the `$dir` value with your `formData` in ajax call as :

```
function uploadFormData(formData) {
   formData.append('dir', <?php echo $dir; ?>);
    $.ajax({
        url: "sfm",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#drop-area').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Run a `print_r($_POST);` at your ajax request page and take a look at the data which you are getting from your request so then you will know exactly how to grab the data in `PHP`